# MVC 3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a table (simulating a grid behaviour):

```
<table class="searchResult" border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>First Name"</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>@foreach (var per in @Model) {
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>+</td>
        <td>@per.LastName</td>
        <td>@per.MiddleName</td>
        <td>@per.FirstName</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td colspan="11">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Home Address: @per.HomeAddress
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         Race : @per.Race
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>`
    </tr>}
</tbody>
```

The "+" on the row with class="parent" expands the row with class="child"(expand/collapse)

jquery for expanding and collapsing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.searchResult').each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('tr.child').hide();
        $table.find('.parent').click(function () {
            var sign = $.trim($(this).find('td:first').text());
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();
            if (sign == '+')
                $(this).find('td:first').text('-');
            else
                $(this).find('td:first').text('+');
        });
    });
});
```

My question is

1. How can I apply alternate rows style to rows with class="parent"?
2. If there is multiple records with exact same First Name, Middle Name and Last Name the rows should be hi-lighted with green.(the Model is ordered by LastName ThenBy MiddleName then by FirstName)

I am very new to jquery and mvc, 10 to be exact. I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1)

```
$(function() {
    var index = 1;
    $("tr.parent").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings().each(function() {
           if ($(this).hasClass("parent")) {
             return false; // stop execution
          }
          else if ((++index % 4) == 1) {
              $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Part 2)

```
@{
    var namesWithIndex = Model.Select(pers => pers.FirstName + pers.MiddleName + pers.LastName);
    var duplicateRows = Model.Where(pers => namesWithIndex.Count(name => pers .FirstName + pers .MiddleName + pers.LastName == name) > 1);
}
```

Then just check to see if the current person is in that duplicateRows list and give them another css class to highlight the background-color as green.

```
 <tbody>@foreach (var per in @Model) {
 <tr class="parent @(duplicateRows.Contains(per)?"highlightGreen":string.Empty)  " >
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob. I tried part 1 http://jsfiddle.net/hRpAw/173/   am I missing something.. the alternating style work individually but not when inculded in tr.parent {
//        put alternate styles here
}

Comment: NP, I adjusted part 2 to be a little bit more succinct and not require indexing.

Comment: Problem in the fiddle was you weren't using the . operator before the searchResult class name, also nesting CSS like that didn't seem to work for me. I've updated the answer.

Comment: tr.parent:nth-child(odd) and (even) does not work either. Odd/Even gets row 2n+1/2n rows but what I am looking for is 4n+1/4n-1 rows. I was looking at eq but i am not sure how exactly it works...

Comment: @user2225604 did you see my answer?

Comment: :nth-child(N) where N can be 4n or 4n-1 etc.

Comment: Yes i did Hanlet. Thank you for the reply. It works in jsFiddle. its exactly what i was looking for but for some reason it just does not work when i put it script tag in View

Comment: I tested mine with jsFiddle and it should work exactly as you asked.

Comment: Also don't forget to choose your final best answer, it's worth 2 rep to you and 15 rep to us =)

Comment: @ Rob can you share the link of jsfiddle. I could not get it working http://jsfiddle.net/hRpAw/175/ Am i missing something

Comment: @Hanlet I figured why it is not working. We are using old version of IE. so even does not work. it works fine in chrome.

Comment: @user2225604 I updated your jsfiddle. You asked for a 4n selector, you could change the %4 to %anything for that frequency of highlighting. You didn't have a highlighted css class on the fiddle or that many child entries to a parent.

Answer (score 1):

For your first request CSS `nth-child(even)` or `nth-child(odd)` might not exactly work because your rows with class `parent` might not exactly be `evens` or `odd` in the order they appear, these can be easily targeted with a jQuery selector however:

```
$(".parent:even").each(function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color","#CCC");
});
```

For the second request, try this:

```
var cats = [];
$('.child').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if ($.inArray(text, cats) === -1) {
        cats.push(text);
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
    }
});
```

This assumes the entire content of the row already exists. It might not exactly work as you want it, so you might have to adjust it a little to your needs.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/atngN/

Comment: Hanlet I figured why it is not working. We are using old version of IE. so even does not work. it works fine in chrome